# How to run software with system start

Tags: cron, clamav, ps

I have a problem to set run software with system start. I have ubuntu 20.04. I tried to insert these lines to etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/clamonacc
```

it doesn't work. Second try was to insert it to cron like this:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/clamonacc
```

it also doesn't work. I am trying to check this by this command

```
ps -e | grep 'clam*'
```

In output there is nothing about clamonacc. If I run it manually as root, it works without any problem and I can find the running process in ps. Could someone help me how to debug this, where is the problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: An easier way may be to use the Ubuntu `Startup Applications Preferences` app. But if you want to use your existing methods why not add output to a log file then you can see if the log file exists, what date/time it was last written to and any results/errors. e.g. `@reboot /usr/bin/clamonacc >> /path/to/my/logfile.log 2>&1`

Comment: `cron` jobs are in a different run-time environment. Compare the output of `(env|sort;alias; set)` in both `cron` and GUI environments. Search the internet for "cron environment".